# php html audio player disappears

Tags: php, html, audio

When I code the src with an .aac I cannot get the audio player to work

```
'<audio controls ><source type="audio/aac" src="'.$mTheMediaLocation.'" ></audio>'
```

If I Build the data from a data string then It's fine..

```
<audio controls id="myAudio"><source src="data:audio/aac;base64,'.base64_encode($mTheMediaData).'"></audio>'
```

I want the src to be a file, I'm aware of browser support etc. BUT if the one works surely there is a way to get the other to work aswell ?

Comment: Check if the url is correct. Check browser console.

Comment: HTTP "Content-Type" of "audio/x-aac" is not supported.

Comment: So how does it support the data string but not the actual file